# How to properly escape values in meta query

Tags: meta-query

I found this filter some time ago at [How to filter my search in post if contains a word in title, content or excerpt?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/286081/how-to-filter-my-search-in-post-if-contains-a-word-in-title-content-or-excerpt)

It worked well.  But now I am getting an error message of `like_escape is deprecated since version 4.0.0! Use wpdb::esc_like()`

It tried replacing esc_like, with `wpdb::_esc_like`, but that resulted in a message of:

```
Deprecated: Non-static method wpdb::escape()
```

If I removed `like_escape` and just left the query inside `esc_sql` would that be secure enough?

I am open to a better way to structure this.

Thanks.

```php
function general_filter( $where, &$wp_query )
{
    global $wpdb;
    if ( $search_term = $wp_query->get( 'search_prod_title' ) ) {
        $where .= ' AND (' . $wpdb->posts . '.post_title LIKE \'%' . esc_sql( like_escape( $search_term ) ) . '%\' OR ' . $wpdb->posts . ' .post_excerpt LIKE \'%' . esc_sql( like_escape( $search_term ) ) . '%\' OR ' . $wpdb->posts . ' .post_content LIKE \'%' . esc_sql( like_escape( $search_term ) ) . '%\')';
    }
    return $where;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you've interpreted `wpdb::esc_like` as a literal copy paste, and not a direction, and used it as a static function, when it is not a static function.

Good:

```php
global $wpdb;
$foo = $wpdb->esc_like( $bar );
```

Bad:

```php
$foo = wpdb::esc_like( $bar );
```

Other things to note:

- The `&` in `&$wp_query )` is a holdover from PHP 4 that they fixed in PHP 5. However, a lot of WP devs weren't sure and didn't know this and copy pasted it everywhere. You should remove the `&`. The same with `&$this`, change it to `$this`. WordPress doesn't even run on PHP 4.x
- The filter you found was just that persons attempt that they were asking how to fix, there are other ways to do what you want
- An actual search solution will massively outperform this without needing to write custom SQL. Look into solutions such as Elasticsearch, Solr, etc
- Generally it's far safer to use `$wpdb->prepare`, though sometimes that isn't always possible. Needing to write SQL for WP tables is normally a warning sign that you're doing something wrong.
- If you used double quotes then you wouldn't need to slash escape your single quotes inside the SQL string. E.g. `"'test'"` vs `'\'test\''`

Comment: Tom, thank you for your insights on this.  I finally got the queries working.
I am not familiar with Elasticsearch or Solr.  This client's website does not have a lot of traffic.  Would those services be a good fit for smaller websites?

Comment: Depends how rich your client is, what their budget is for hosting and search, and how highly they value it. You should price up the options and have a conversation with them